# Heroku: Sendgrid add-on with custom domain

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, heroku, devise, sendgrid

I'm trying to set up the Heroku Sengrid plugin for a custom domain. I need it because we have ssl certificate on the custom domain, not on the basic .herokuapp.com.

The feature: reset your password email from devise.

In my config/environments/production.rb, I have this line:

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => ENV['MAILER_URL'] }
```

When the MAILER_URL variable is set to `basic_domain.herokuapp.com`, I can send an email for resetting a password. But the links in it will lead to the scary page **this site is not secure, are you sure?**.

I can also set the MAILER_URL variable to `great_custom_domain.com`, which has an ssl certificate. But the email will never be send, and in my server log I can read :

> Net::SMTPAuthenticationError (451 Authentication failed: Could not authenticate)`.

After reading other answers, I double checked the Sendgrid credentials.